# Why am i getting the binary operator expected error

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to write a shell script to check if there's a file existing that ends with .txt using an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within single bracket conditionals, all of the [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) will occur, particularly in this case Filename expansion.

The condional construct acts upon the *number* of arguments it's given: `-f` expects exactly one argument to follow it, a filename. Apparently your `*.txt`  pattern matches more than one file.

If your shell is bash, you can do

```sh
files=(*.txt)
if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then ...
```

or, more portably:

```sh
count=0
for file in *.txt; do 
  count=1
  break
done
if [ "$count" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "no *.txt files"
else
  echo "at least one *.txt file"
fi
```

---

I finally get your perspective now. I've been giving you some incomplete advice. This is what you need:

```sh
for f in *.txt; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    do_something_with "$f"
  fi
done
```

The reason: if there are *no files matching the pattern* then the shell *leaves the patten as a plain string*. On the first iteration of the loop, we have `f="*.txt"` and `mv` responds with "file not found".

I'm used to working in bash with the `nullglob` option that handles this edge case.

Comment: I am using the sh shell and I'm still a bit confused. I'm wondering if you'd be able to help me fix it when layed out like this?
                        if [ -f *.txt ]
                        then
                                for file in *.txt
                                do
                                        echo moving $file ...
                                        mv $file text
                                        filesMoved=$((filesMoved+1))
                                done
                        fi

Comment: Code can't be formatted in comments. Add it do your question [with proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Oh ok, I've added it

Comment: `[ -f *.txt ]` is throwing the error: you need to remove it from your code. If there are no .txt files, the for loop body will not execute, so you don't need the guard in front of it.

Comment: I can't remember how it worked previously but I had it doing something similar like that and it was working but I deleted my script on accident. but it was able to work with multiple files ending with *.txt and moving the files before idk why it's not now.

Comment: not sure why but the loop still activates for some reason when i remove the if statement. and says it can't mv the file as there's no file that exists with the name.